# nhibernate fill class with custom data from different tables

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate

I have a web application (asp.net + SQL db) and I'm mapping it with nHibernate with relative success =).

This web reads an Oracle db (from an ERP system), collects and display data from it but its not using nHibernate for this task.

I have done several reports each one with its own vb.net class that I fill with intrincated queries, 
collecting data from a bunch of Oracle tables. So my question is:

*Can i do an specific hql query and fill my vb.class in a custom way (Maybe not mapping it), specifying one by one which column of my query fills each property?*

===================== EDIT WITH SOLUTION =====================

Just if someone need the resolution, I post the solution in an example.

```
Public Class classExample
    Private pProperty1 As Decimal
    Private pProperty2 As String

    Public Property Property1() As Decimal
        Get
            Property1 = pProperty1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Decimal)
            pProperty1 = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Property2() As String
        Get
            Property2 = pProperty2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            pProperty2 = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overloads Function Load() As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of classExample)
        Using session As NHibernate.ISession = ISessionFactory.OpenSession()
            Dim strsql As String = "SELECT.... FROM...."
            Dim Query As NHibernate.IQuery = session.CreateSQLQuery(strsql)
            Query.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(Of classExample))
            Return Query.List(Of classExample)()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a result transformer as [here](/a/2207507/1178314) (see second code block).

Comment: Thank you so much Frédéric! I didn't know of those and i was fighting with the class and mapping to make them work. =)

Comment: If you use named queries (queries written in mappings with `<query>` tags, outside of `<class>` definition), you should be able to do that in mappings too. This have the additional benefit of validating your queries on session factory boot-strapping (so usually very early in the application use), instead of validating them only on call (so maybe outside your functional tests coverage).